# Visual studio debugger show char as unsigned char

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

In the debugger, even with the [/J (Default char Type Is unsigned)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d294k5z.aspx) compiler option, the debugger shows chars as signed down at the bottom. How do I get it to show them as unsigned?

Comment: Have you tried doing a casting with CType?

Answer (score 1):

Watch window allows you to add [format specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt.aspx) to variables that are being watched. If you have a variable `ch` of type `char`, you can watch it as unsigned by specifying `ch,u` in Watch window. You can't add format specifiers in Autos and Locals windows, though. Format specifiers can be applied to arrays as well.

Comment: That's fine, if you don't mind constantly adding and removing variables from watch depending on what scope you're in. I need a way for it to show as unsigned in autos/locals